# jq query to find nested value and return parent values

Tags: json, jq, parent

having trouble finding this, maybe it's just my search terms or who knows.

basically, i have a series of arrays mapping keyspaces to destination DBs for a large noSQL migration, in order for us to more easily script data movement. i'll include sample JSON below.

it's nested basically like: `environment >> { [ target DB ] >> [ list of keyspaces ] }, { [ target DB ] >> [ list of keyspaces ] }`

my intent was to update my migration script to more intelligently determine where things go based on which environment is specified, etc and require less user input or "figuring things out".

here's sample JSON:

```
{
    "Prod": [
        {
            "prod1": [
                "prod_db1",
                "prod_db2",
                "prod_d31",
                "prod_db4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "prod2": [
                "prod_db5",
                "prod_db6",
                "prod_db7",
                "prod_db8"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

assuming i'm able to provide keyspace and environment to the script, and use those as variables in my jq query, is there a way to search for the keyspace and return the value for one level up? IE, i know i can do something like:

```
!#/bin/bash
ENV="Prod"
jq '.."${ENV}"[][]' env.json
```

to just get the DBs in the prod environment. but if i'm searching for `prod_db6' how can i return the value` prod2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_entries` to decompose an object into an array of key-value pairs, then `IN` to search in the value's array, and finally return the key:

```bash
jq -r --arg env "Prod" --arg ksp "prod_db6" '
  .[$env][] | to_entries[] | select(IN(.value[]; $ksp)).key
' env.json
```

```
prod2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EfTE62WLel5)

Comment: Do you know if `IN` does an _equality_ check or a _contains_ check?  I'm not happy this is true: `["foo", "bar"] | contains(["oo"])`

Comment: Answering my own question: it is equality (happy day!) `("foo", "bar") | IN("oo")` => `false, false`

Comment: @glennjackman `IN/1` and `IN/2` are [defined](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L292-L293) as `def IN(s): any(s == .; .);` and `def IN(src; s): any(src == s; .);`, respectively, so they check for equality `==`.

Comment: had to grab jq v1.6, v1.5 is what's available thru packages on our amazon linux 2 instances, but this worked. thanks!

Comment: @mrkurtz `IN/2` is the (only) part requiring jq 1.6 - You could have also provided its definition (see my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747799/jq-query-to-find-nested-value-and-return-parent-values/73747855#comment130226485_73747855)) at the beginning of your filter, and it would have worked also with jq 1.5

Comment: If your jq does not have `IN/2` or if you are using jaq, you could write `any(.value[]; . == $ksp)`